# writing python request using "post" to flask server as binary file

Tags: python, file, post, flask, binary

My client use this code to upload file and some json to a flask server :

```
datas = {'CurrentMail': "AA", 'STRUserUUID1': "BB", 'FirstName': "ZZ",     'LastName': "ZZ",  'EE': "RR", 'JobRole': "TT"  }

#sending user infos to app server using python "requests"
url = "http://10.100.2.6:80/customerupdate"
def send_request():
    payload = datas
    local_file_to_send = 'user_picture.jpg' 
    files = {
     'json': (None, json.dumps(payload), 'application/json'),
     'file': (os.path.basename(local_file_to_send), open(local_file_to_send, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)

send_request()
```

on My server

On Flask Server side :

```
import sys, os, logging, time, datetime, json, uuid, requests, ast
from flask import Flask, request , render_template
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.debug = True

class OPERATIONS(Resource):
    @app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
    def hello_world():
        return 'Hello World!'

    @app.route('/customerupdate',methods=['GET','POST'])
    def customerupdate():
        print "************DEBUG 1 ***********"
        RequestValues = request.values
        print RequestValues
        print "************DEBUG 2 ***********"
        RequestForm = request.form
        print RequestForm
        print "************DEBUG 2-1 ***********"
        so = RequestForm
        json_of_metadatas = so.to_dict(flat=False)
        print json_of_metadatas
        print "************DEBUG 2-2 ***********"
        MetdatasFromJSON = json_of_metadatas['json']
        print MetdatasFromJSON          
        print "************DEBUG 2-3 ***********"
        MetdatasFromJSON0 = MetdatasFromJSON[0]
        print MetdatasFromJSON0
        print "************DEBUG 3-5 ***********"
        strMetdatasFromJSON0 = str(MetdatasFromJSON0)
        MetdatasDICT = ast.literal_eval(strMetdatasFromJSON0)
        print MetdatasDICT
        print "************DEBUG 3-5 ***********"
        for key in MetdatasDICT :
            print "key: %s , value: %s" % (key, MetdatasDICT[key])
        print "************DEBUG 4 ***********"
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        print "FILE SAVED LOCALY"
        return 'JSON of customer posted'
```

So I could save some metadatas and the file itself on my server. What I would like to do now is to save the complete "POST" as raw binary file.

AS mentionned is some thread in SO, I tried using :

```
        # test 1
        foo = request.get_data()
        #TEST 2
        foo = request.files
        #test 3
        foo = request.stream.read()

        f = request.files['file']
        fname = f.filename
        #Using Hexa for the binary name and prefix bin
        fname_hexa = fname.encode("hex")
        bin_file_name="%s_%s"%("bin",fname_hexa)
        with open(bin_file_name, 'wb') as output_file_bin:
            output_file_bin.write(**foo**)
            output_file_bin.close()
```

But I get an empty file whatever the method used to right "foo" : get_data() and stream.read()
If I use only "files", I got an error message from my flask server :

```
  TypeError: argument 1 must be convertible to a buffer, not ImmutableMultiDict
```